# PBX configuration in Elastix is empty

Tags: elastix

After I add call center module,there is nothing in PBX configuration tab (*ex. add extension and so on* ).

Before I add call center module, I add 2 extensions but now there is not any thing. 
I think it is stop working!I can't add sip. what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

Install pbx menu from:

```
/usr/bin/elastix-menumerge /usr/share/elastix/module_installer/elastix-pbx-(version for example:)2.0-../elastix-pbx .
```